vcpkg error: BUILD_FAILED when "Getting CMake variables for x64-windows"
I'm trying to install ffmpeg via vcpkg on Windows by running the following command:
vcpkg.exe install ffmpeg
The installation throws an error when getting CMake variables for x64-windows.
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-windows
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:127 (message):
    Command failed: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe" -v
    Working Directory: C:/Users/xxxxx/vcpkg/buildtrees/pkgconf/x64-windows-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\xxxxx\vcpkg\buildtrees\pkgconf\cmake-get-vars-x64-windows-dbg-CMakeCache.txt.log
      C:\Users\xxxxx\vcpkg\buildtrees\pkgconf\cmake-get-vars-x64-windows-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      C:\Users\xxxxx\vcpkg\buildtrees\pkgconf\cmake-get-vars-x64-windows-dbg-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
      C:\Users\xxxxx\vcpkg\buildtrees\pkgconf\cmake-get-vars-x64-windows-rel-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
      C:\Users\xxxxx\vcpkg\buildtrees\pkgconf\cmake-get-vars-x64-windows-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_configure.cmake:269 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake-get-vars/vcpkg_cmake_get_vars.cmake:15 (vcpkg_cmake_configure)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-tool-meson/vcpkg_configure_meson.cmake:323 (vcpkg_cmake_get_vars)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-tool-meson/vcpkg_configure_meson.cmake:458 (vcpkg_generate_meson_cmd_args)
  ports/pkgconf/portfile.cmake:9 (vcpkg_configure_meson)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)


error: building pkgconf:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
See https://learn.microsoft.com/vcpkg/troubleshoot/build-failures?WT.mc_id=vcpkg_inproduct_cli for more information.
Elapsed time to handle pkgconf:x64-windows: 1.9 s
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+pkgconf
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=xxxxx

What does this error mean? The suggested git pull and vcpkg update didn't solve the error. The directory is up to date.
PS: I opened logs, but I have no idea how to solve the error. I don't understand them.
